# Azure Blob Storage - 404 when i save to file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have another problem with Azure Blob Storage, this time with downloading. I get a list of files without a problem, unfortunately when I want to download it I get a 404 error that the file was not found.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace BlobStorage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount backupStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                "{connectionString}");

            var backupBlobClient = backupStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var backupContainer = backupBlobClient.GetContainerReference("{container-name");

            var list = backupContainer.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);

            foreach (var blob in list)
            {
                var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = backupContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);

                string destinationPath = string.Format(@"D:\" + blobFileName +".txt");

                blockBlob.DownloadToFile(destinationPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: "The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not found."
>
> Internal exception WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (404) Not found.

And points to the line:

```
blockBlob.DownloadToFile (destinationPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

A file like this most exists in blob storage. When I enter the blob editions, copy the url to a file, I can download it through the browser without any problem. Unfortunately, I can not download it from the application level due to a 404 error.

Only why does such a file exist?

Comment: Is your blob inside a virtual folder?

Comment: Yes, example path tempdata/ExampleIotHub/02/2019/05/14/39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you're getting the blob name in the following line of code:

```
var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
```

Considering, the path is `tempdata/ExampleIotHub/02/2019/05/14/39`, the blob's name is `ExampleIotHub/02/2019/05/14/39` (assuming your container name is `tempdata`) however the blobFileName you're getting is just 39 (please see examples [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netframework-4.8#examples)). Since there is no blob by the name `39`, you're getting this 404 error.

I suggest you try by doing something like the following:

```
foreach (var blob in list)
{
    var localFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blob as CloudBlockBlob;
    if (blockBlob != null)
    {
      string destinationPath = string.Format(@"D:\" + localFileName +".txt");

      blockBlob.DownloadToFile(destinationPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }
}
```

Please note that I have not tried running this code so there may be some errors.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer :) Your code has solved my problem, now it saves the files correctly. Thank you very much for your help.